# Automatically scale image while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I have an img inside a div tag, and currently I am using the CSS

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This currently keeps the images fitting inside the div, which is what I wanted. However, if the image file is smaller than the div, the image will not be the maximum size it can be. Is there an easy way to maximise the image, while keeping the image inside the div, and keeping the original aspect ratio?

I've tried setting the height to 100%, with a max-width of 100%, but this distorts the image, which is not what I'm looking for.
I also tried `object-fit: contain;`, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks :)

Comment: `max-width` will limit the image to 100% of the image's native width. What that means is, if your image has a width of 400px and the div has a width of 600px, then the image will not fill the full width of the div as it can only stretch to 400px because of `max-width`. Are any of you're DIVs fixed width/height?

Comment: All the divs resize dependent on the screen size. It does work as it is, just if the images have smaller resolutions, it's not going to work as intended, or if someone has a massive screen.

Answer (score 3):

@Michelangelo's answer is another way to achieve your objective. If you want your image to be inside a `img` tag (like your original post), keep your `max-width` and `max-height` values, and put one of these inside your CSS class:

1) Keep aspect ratio based on width:

```
width: 300px; /* Your preferred width */
height: auto;
```

2) Keep aspect ratio based on height:

```
width: auto;
height: 300px; /* Your preferred height */
```

I would also suggest you to take a look at the `object-fit` property here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

It kinda acts as `background-size` property when you put values like `contain` or `cover`, with the plus that you can specify `width` and `height` without complicating your layout / DOM hierarchy. It comes very handy when dealing with intrinsic sizes of elements.

Comment: I didn't want to have any absolute values for the image, I wanted it to be fully responsive, and resize for any screen. Also I tried the object-fit and it just did nothing, not sure why

Comment: You can put any allowed CSS value in `width` and `height` properties. You can even put `calc` as value. Take a look here: https://www.w3resource.com/css/CSS-values.php

Answer (score 1):

Try doing adding it as background, then you can do this:

```
div {
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This works fine if you're looking to do background images, but not so great if it's general use images like a profile photo, image gallery, etc. Especially if the image is placed via CMS.

Comment: I'm assuming where you put ````background-size: cover;```` it was meant to be ````contain````?  Anyway I tried this and it seems as though it thinks the div is larger than it actually is, so the top and bottom of the image is still not showing. In the Chrome DevTools it shows the div to be the correct size, but the images are not showing that way.  It may be useful information that this div is inside a bootstrap carousel.

Comment: @hungerstar Yes, but this the only way you don't get stretched images...and that is what op tries to avoid. So, I don't know what OP is using it for but this is how I always do an image that keeps its original size. And yes there are downsides.

Comment: @RobertClarke No, cover will maintain the image aspect ratio as is and cut off on certain resolutions. That is the trade-off.

Comment: `object-fit` is a solution and allows you to use `<img>` as long as [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) is acceptable. It can also be polyfilled.

Comment: When scaling images beyond their native resolution or even requirements like must fill the width of the container, concessions will have to be made (cropping, pixelation, white space etc) depending on how sizing is applied (cover, contain, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the image as an HTML element and not a CSS background, I would use object-fit. There are browser support limitations with this CSS property.

https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

You could use a polyfill to combat this. Such as:
https://github.com/fregante/object-fit-images

An example of what I believe you're after could be:
https://codepen.io/bin-man/pen/NWKNWLm

```
.image-container img {
  object-fit: cover; 
}
```

You can play around with the image sizes and remove object-fit to see how it behaves.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need... Please run the code snippet...

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.wellnesspetfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/blog_feature/public/media/images/6615505_950x400.jpg?itok=ylLXPrq6" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Kitten_in_Rizal_Park%2C_Manila.jpg" />
</div>
```